# Drawing overlapping circles with alpha channeling

Tags: html, algorithm, canvas, geometry

This question has sort of been answered here: [Combined area of overlapping circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles)

My problem is more specific though. I have an arbitrary number of arbitrarily sized circles inside other arbitrarily sized circles, to make a target-like image:

[image]

This image must have some amount of transparency. The transparency must be the same throughout the entire shape. Then, there's an arbitrary number of these shapes that can overlap, and it needs to look like this:

[image]

The transparency amount must stay the same no matter how much they overlap.

The only thing I can think of to pull this off is to iterate through every pixel on the canvas and calculate what color the pixel should be based on its distance from the center of each circle, but this takes too long. I want the circles to be draggable as well, so this needs to be pretty fast. Is there a better way to do this? (Sorry about my poor GIMP skills)

Comment: Do the circles share same opacity overall or are the individual circles having different opacity?

Comment: I think I'm safe with each circle having the same opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do natively without using pixel manipulation or any library.

Provided the transparency is the same for all the circles it is pretty straight forward.

### Solution

[image: snapshot]
<sup>Circles on top of some random background</sup>

What you need to do is to:

- Allocate an off-screen canvas where circles are drawn as solids (no transparency)
- Draw the circles in three steps.
- All the circles' red surface first, then all the circles' blue surface and so on.
- Set global alpha for transparency for main (visible) canvas
- Clear both canvases
- Draw off-screen canvas to main canvas

Your circle function can look something like this:

```
function drawCircle(x, y, r, step) {

    ctx.beginPath();

    switch (step) {
        case 0:  // step 0, outer circle red
            ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
            break;

        case 1:  // step 1, middle circle blue
            ctx.fillStyle = '#00f';
            r *= 0.67;
            break;

        case 2:  // step 2, inner circle green
            ctx.fillStyle = '#0f0';
            r *= 0.33;
            break;
    }
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

The function takes the `x` and `y` center point as well as `radius`. But in addition it takes a `step` value between 0 and 2 which determines which surface is being drawn. This will be important in the next steps.

First we can define an array holding all the circles we want to draw:

```
var circs = [
    //x   y    r   dx dy (the last two for animation only)
    [100, 100, 50, 2, 1],
    [200, 200, 50, -2, -3],
    [150, 50, 50, 3, -1]
];
```

From here you would drag them, offset x and y and then redraw them, but for demo's sake I'll animate them.

Before we draw we set the global alpha on the main canvas (the off-screen is kept solid):

```
mctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;  // main canvas
```

And the animation loop:

```
function start() {
    
    // clear off-screen canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, w, h);

    // clear main canvas
    mctx.clearRect(0,0, w, h);

    var t = 0, i, c;

    // outer step loop
    for(; t < 3; t++) {

        // draw all circles at current step
        for(i = 0; c = circs[i]; i++) {
            drawCircle(c[0], c[1], c[2], t);
        }
    }

    // re-position circles for animation
    for(i = 0;c = circs[i]; i++) {
        c[0] += c[3];  /// add delta to x
        c[1] += c[4];  /// add delta to y

        // reverse deltas if at boundaries
        if (c[0] < 0 || c[0] > w) c[3] = -c[3];
        if (c[1] < 0 || c[1] > h) c[4] = -c[4];
    }

    // draw off-screen to main canvas        
    mctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 0, 0);

    // loop animation
    requestAnimationFrame(start);
}
```

The global alpha can be reset for each operation in case you want to draw other elements to the canvas - or use a second on-screen canvas to hold static content.

## Demo

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var w = demo.width, h = demo.height;

var ocanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
ocanvas.width = w;
ocanvas.height = h;

var ctx = ocanvas.getContext('2d');
var mctx = demo.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/CHPdL2y.png';

/// key to it all
mctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;

var circs = [
    //x   y    r   dx   dy
    [100, 100, 50,  2  ,  1.5],
    [200, 200, 70, -2  , -3],
    [150,  50, 50,  3  , -1],
    [150,  50, 30,  4  ,  4],
    [150,  50, 20, -3  , -2],
    [100, 100, 55,  2.5,  2.5],
    [200, 200, 75, -1  , -2.5],
    [150,  50, 45,  3.5, -2],
    [150,  50, 35,  5  ,  2],
    [150,  50, 25, -1.2, -5]
];

function drawCircle(x, y, r, step) {

    ctx.beginPath();

    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
            break;
        case 1:
            ctx.fillStyle = '#00f';
            r *= 0.67;
            break;
        case 2:
            ctx.fillStyle = '#0f0';
            r *= 0.33;
            break;
    }
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

function start() {
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    mctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var i = 0, t, c;
    for(t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
        for(i = 0; c = circs[i]; i++) {
            drawCircle(c[0], c[1], c[2], t);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0;c = circs[i]; i++) {
        c[0] += c[3];
        c[1] += c[4];
        if (c[0] < 0 || c[0] > w) c[3] = -c[3];
        if (c[1] < 0 || c[1] > h) c[4] = -c[4];
    }
    
    mctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 0, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(start);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    background:url(//i.stack.imgur.com/b8eCZ.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="demo" width="500" height="333"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a library like RaphaelJS. It is capable of more than what you ask for here.

Edit: You can apply alpha transparency through js by programmatically determining the distance between centres (D) and comparing it with the sum of the radii (S). If D < S, then they overlap so take care of red circles.

(http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out. It'll make drawing easier at the very least.