# How to efficiently find the total area of a union of circles?

Tags: geometry, gis, geo

I have a data set defined as:

```
 [
  [lat, long, radius],
  [lat, long, radius],
  ... (100-10k)
  [lat, long, radius]
 ]
```

How can I calculate the area of the reunion of all the circles?
The sum would be the total area of all the circles - the intersection (to remove duplicate counts)?

Comment: FYI, this is known as the "union".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combined area of overlapping circles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles)

Comment: @Sneftel corrected, it was translation glitch :) , it's "reunion" in my native language, thought it was incorrect hence the extra explanation

Comment: @clickstefan Note that depending on your purposes, rasterizing and counting the pixels may be "good enough".  And note also, there is a [GIS stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115927/)...as this is a feature you'd hope a vector system would be able to take care of for you, so if you were to frame it in terms of a particular package that would be a good place for it.

Comment: thanks to all,  I've converted the circles to polygons and used geoPHP lib union as it was "good enough" for my use-case. Also I need the polygon for further intersections, so 2 hits with one stone :)