# How to calculate total area covered by overlapping circles in Java

Tags: java, google-maps, math, geolocation, geometry

I am developing an android app which involves calculating the total area covered by a set of circles on a map.

Say I have a `List` of `Circle`s, each `Circle` has fields `double longitude`, `double latitude`, and `double radius`.

```
List<Circles> circles;

class Circle {
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    double radius;
}
```

These circles may or may not overlap, they can be a thousand miles away from each other or they can be all piled up on top of each other.

I want to calculate the total combined area of these `Circle`s (with their overlapping taken into account of course). What would be a good algorithm (or a library function if there exists) to use for this purpose?

Comment: This is more of a mathematical problem rather than a programming one. You need to find a formula that calculates the area of overlapping circles.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles/1667789#1667789

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here

Comment: _I am developing an android app_ There is a limit of no more than five tags per question. I suggest you remove one of the tags and replace it with the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) tag in order to attract Android developers who may be able to help you.

Comment: @Abra thank you for your suggestion, but I think the problem is less related to the domain of Android, but more of a generic algorithm question, that's why I didn't put Android in there to avoid perplexing the context.

Comment: I first voted to close this as a duplicate of the question to which @Madstuffs refers.  But on reflection, this requires the computation of the area of *spherical caps* not of circles.  It ain't just pi-r-squared.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to cluster the overlapping circles:

```
Make each circle its own cluster
Repeat (until convergence):
  For each cluster:
     For each other cluster:
        Merge clusters if any of their circles overlap
```

Then you calculate the area of each cluster using [Combined area of overlapping circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Finally, you sum all clusters.