How do I find the area of a shape formed by connecting X mile radius circles around Latitude Longitude Coordinates in Python
I have a list of locations grouped by a common identifier. I have the Latitude and Longitude for each location. I want to form a 15-mile radius circle around each pair of coordinates and then find the total area of the shape formed by those 15-mile radius circles. Each 15-mile radius circles overlaps with at least one of the other circles to form a unified shape

I've tried calculating the area but it seems to be calculating the area of each circle and summing it up rather than the shape overall (not double counting overlapping area)
def calculate_circle_area(radius_miles):
    return math.pi * (radius_miles ** 2)

# Calculate total area covered by circles in square miles
total_area_covered = filtered_df['CircleRadiusMiles'].apply(lambda r: calculate_circle_area(r)).sum()


You have mostly a math problem, not a programming problem. It seems it has already been described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles
